# Buffer concatenation method

Tags: c#, array

Is there any way to improve or optimize the speed of this? I can't think of any ways to do it in one pass.

```
static byte[] ConcatenateBuffers(params byte[][] list)
{
    int totalLen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
        totalLen += list[i].Length;
    byte[] ret = new byte[totalLen];
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
    {
        Array.ConstrainedCopy(list[i], 0, ret, offset, list[i].Length);
        offset += list[i].Length;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to optimize for? Speed? Size? Clarity?

Comment: Mostly speed, but this is an interactive client application so I don't need to go to a lower level language to get the absolute fastest method.

Comment: Your length computation can suffer from integer overflow, in which case the array copying will throw an exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're optimizing for performance it does not get much better than that. In particular it is a valuable optimization to compute the exact result array length.

I'm not sure why you used `ConstrainedCopy` which is a very esoteric feature. `Copy` is faster. `ConstrainedCopy` is, I believe, used for code that must not be interrupted by a `ThreadAbortException`. The concept is called a constrained execution region and it's useless in practice because programming in the presence of thread aborts is essentially impossible. The consensus is to never abort a thread except your own (ASP.NET violates that rule which must be very unsafe).

The code is of good quality as well. I'd use `foreach` to traverse the `list`. It compiles to the same code that you wrote but is nicer.

Answers have been proposed that use `List<byte>` or LINQ. These will be *far* slower (e.g. 10-100x). This is because `Array.Copy` is a facade over `memmove` (which is similar to `memcpy` but it handles overlapping regions as well). The difference becomes noticeable even with common network speeds (10MB/s) and certainly with disk speeds (100MB/s and up).

If you don't care about performance or the amount of data processed is small than you can use slower approaches. Some people find such code better and I'd certainly understand why. The LINQ approach using `Concat` is extremely concise and self-documenting.

Comment: I had no idea `Array.Copy` could specify the location. I always used `Array.ConstrainedCopy` because I thought that it was the version that allowed me to specify the location of the data in the new array.

Comment: +1: this seems like the most appropriate answer so far. Minor nitpick: the documentation for `Array.Copy` mentions that it's equivalent to `memmove`, not `memcpy`, the difference being that overlap between the source and destination is allowed.

Comment: "Answers have been proposed that use List<byte> or LINQ. These will be far slower" You might think, but the runtime is very good at optimising LINQ.

Comment: @PeteKirkham LINQ is not specifically targeted by the JIT for optimizations. This has recently been proposed on GitHub but it's hard. I know from experience that LINQ to object queries execute almost literally on the CPU causing enormous runtime increases (and allocations diminishing overall application scalability due to GC involvement).

Comment: @usr Yes, generally I'd assume that LINQ would be slower, but from measuring this case is not significantly slower. It certainly can be slower is some cases, so (as for anything performance related) you must measure and use that evidence before you make any statements about what is fast enough or too slow.  I didn't mean to imply that the JIT specifically targeted LINQ itself, only that it was good at optimising the sort of code LINQ generates.I wouldn't expect JIT to optimise inefficient algorithms or reorder complex queries for best execution.

Comment: @PeteKirkham did you measure this case? I'd bet money that the LINQ version is >10x slower for lists of maybe 100 bytes. I don't know why the LINQ code would ever be faster or even break even but it might happen with tiny arrays for some reason.

Comment: @usr That would have been my expectation, but see my answer. The OP would have to measure for their data, but in the cases I measured it was fairly consistently 4% slower.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I did not notice your answer. I cannot reproduce those numbers with your code, though. Release mode, x64, .NET 4.7. https://imgur.com/a/QGxWw The code is good, it's a well done benchmark and should be reliable. Not sure why we are getting such different results.

Answer (score 10):

I think it's possible to do it all in one line using linq:

```
static byte[] ConcatenateBuffers(params byte[][] list)
{
  return list.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this answer isn't more popular as it seems to me to be the best answer in terms of both clarity and size, and performance wise, looking at Pete's answer, is as near as makes no difference on par with more complicated solutions.

Comment: @Ashigore we don't like the machine taking our jobs :) .

Answer (score 5):

If you are optimising for performance, then you need to measure what you are optimising.

This is a quick mini-benchmark that will give you an idea of what the trade-offs are, you can adjust for the size of data you're expected and it may change the results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace CodeReview184845
{
    delegate byte[] ConcatDelegate(params byte[][] inputs);


    public static class Program
    {
        static byte[] ConcatenateBuffers(params byte[][] list)
        {
            int totalLen = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
                totalLen += list[i].Length;
            byte[] ret = new byte[totalLen];
            int offset = 0;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Array.ConstrainedCopy(item, 0, ret, offset, item.Length);
                offset += item.Length;
            }
            return ret;
        }
        static byte[] ArrayCopyConcat(params byte[][] list)
        {
            int totalLen = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
                totalLen += list[i].Length;
            byte[] ret = new byte[totalLen];
            int offset = 0;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Array.Copy(item, 0, ret, offset, item.Length);
                offset += item.Length;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        static byte[] LinqConcat(params byte[][] list)
        {
            return list.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
        }


        static byte[] BufferConcat(params byte[][] list)
        {
            var ret = new byte[list.Sum(t => t.Length)];
            var offset = 0;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var length = item.Length;
                Buffer.BlockCopy(item, 0, ret, offset, length);
                offset += length;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        static byte[] ConcatWithList(byte[][] list)
        {
            var data = new List<byte>();
            for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < list[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    data.Add(list[i][j]);   // the list automatically resizes
                }
            }

            return data.ToArray();
        }

        static Tuple<string, ConcatDelegate> Test(string name, ConcatDelegate d)
        {
            return new Tuple<string, ConcatDelegate>(name, d);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputs = CreateInputs();

            var tests = new[]
            {
                Test("original", ConcatenateBuffers),
                Test("list", ConcatWithList),
                Test("Array.Copy", ArrayCopyConcat),
                Test("Linq", LinqConcat),
                Test("Buffer", BufferConcat)
            };

            var elapsed = tests.ToDictionary(test => test.Item1, test => new List<long>());

            while (true)
                foreach (var test in tests)
                {
                    Console.Write($"test {test.Item1}\t");
                    Console.Out.Flush();
                    byte[] output = {};

                    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                    for (var run = 0; run < 1000; ++run)
                    output = test.Item2(inputs);

                    var total = Sum(output);

                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    elapsed[test.Item1].Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                    Console.WriteLine($"elapsed {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms (total: {total}) (mean: {Mean(elapsed[test.Item1])} ms) ");
                    Console.Out.Flush();
                }
        }

        private static long Sum(byte[] output)
        {
            var result = 0L;

            foreach (var value in output)
                result += value;

            return result;
        }

        private static long Mean(List<long> times)
        {
            return times.Sum()/ times.Count;
        }

        private static byte[][] CreateInputs()
        {
            var inputs = new byte[100][];

            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.Length; ++i)
            {
                inputs[i] = new byte[500 + 200 * i];
                for (var j = 0; j < inputs[i].Length; ++j)
                    inputs[i][j] = (byte)j;
            }

            return inputs;
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine, after a few runs it settles down to results like:

```
test original   elapsed  429 ms (total: 132052576) (mean:  430 ms)
test list       elapsed 3451 ms (total: 132052576) (mean: 3419 ms)
test Array.Copy elapsed  437 ms (total: 132052576) (mean:  425 ms)
test Linq       elapsed  448 ms (total: 132052576) (mean:  440 ms)
test Buffer     elapsed  443 ms (total: 132052576) (mean:  429 ms)
```

The runtime is *very* good at optimising LINQ. Writing something using a for loop instead of LINQ may give you an extra percent (and in some cases can allow you to perform other optimisations), but very often the difference is lost in the noise.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for this interesting problem. I think your code is good to go, although it isn't quite how I would do it. First, avoid using `array` unless you absolutely need to. `List<T>` is much easier to manage, which compensates for it's nominally larger size in memory. You can then get your data in one pass because a list is resizable.

```
static List<byte> ConcatenateBuffers(params byte[][] list)
```

Now you can do:

```
var data = new List<byte>();
for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < list[i].Length; j++)
    {
        data.Add(list[i][j]);   // the list automatically resizes
    }
}
```

If performance isn't critical, where you need to squeeze the last nanosecond out of performance, I would also consider using `IEnumerable` and `yield`ing results. This constructs a state machine that doesn't do the calculations until you actually ask for them. It has the drawback of having some slight overhead for each call, but if you only need to process a few bytes periodically and the performance cost of processing a chunk of bytes is large, it allows you to do just that, rather than processing the whole set at once--you only process what you need when you need it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < list[i].Length; j++)
    {
        yield return list[i][j];
    }
}
```

Your signature then becomes:

```
static IEnumerable<byte> ConcatenateBuffers(params byte[][] list)
```

For what it's worth, if you want/need to use arrays, what you have is good, and likely as optimal as you will get both memory- and performance-wise.

Comment: Any performance implications with using `List<byte>`? I'm using this for building network packets that get encrypted or appending the IV. It looks like the AesManaged class only uses `byte[]` data types so I think I would have to use `ToArray()` to use them.

Comment: It resizes the array every so often, which adds some overhead. Not enough to be noticeable unless you are running real-time data where every nanosecond counts. However, given that you need the array anyway, I'd just leave it the way you have it. Just wanted to throw some ideas out there.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll accept the answer in a couple of hours.

Comment: Feel free to wait for more answers, but thanks.

Comment: It appears to do the index lookup of `list[i]` twice for every iteration of the inner `for` loop (unless the compiler optimizes that away, which it might?). Can just put `var item = list[i];` above the inner for loop and reference that twice.

Comment: @BradM Yes, we could. However, lists are backed by arrays, so an index-access on a list, AFAIK, is constant-time. Note that you can't access an enumerable by index because enumerables are more like streams than sets.

Comment: Element-by-element copying is slower than copying a memory block (which `ConstrainedCopy` does internally) once you have to copy arrays with more than ~100 items. Performance will differ by orders of magnitude for really large arrays. So unless OP has a special case, where he knows beforehand that he will only be dealing with very small arrays, I would recommend against above refactoring.

Comment: There is a good answer on SO which goes into more detail on the topic, in case anyone is interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33865267/1386995

Comment: @NikitaB Good to know. I know arrays have less overhead because they are able to do that kind of stuff, which is why I added that comment about it likely being as optimal as it will get as the last sentence in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take on the answers presented so far: this does nothing apart from rename variables, and also methods - and I've done nothing but refactor without changing any of the functionality - perhaps it reads a little better, and I hope will be more understandable if one looks at in in 6 months with no recollection of it?

```
    private static byte[] getConcatenatedBuffer(params byte[][] inputBuffer)
    {
        int length = getLengthOfConcatenatedBuffer(inputBuffer);

        byte[] concatenatedBuffer = new byte[length];

        int startingIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputBuffer.Length; ++i)
        {
            int endingIndex = inputBuffer[i].Length;

            Array.ConstrainedCopy(inputBuffer[i], 0, concatenatedBuffer, startingIndex, endingIndex);

            // update index values
            startingIndex += inputBuffer[i].Length;
        }
        return concatenatedBuffer;
    }

    private static int getLengthOfConcatenatedBuffer(byte[][] list)
    {
        int totalLength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
        {
            totalLength += list[i].Length;
        }

        return totalLength;
    }
```